# ASMX web service: result wrapped in extra element

Tags: web-services, soap, web, asmx

I have an ASMX web service running on IIS 8.0. I have a C# web method [methodName] created, it returns a value of type [typeName], the resulting soap body looks like this:

<[methodName]Response><[methodName]Result><[property1 in typeName]>
...

How do I get rid of the first two tags?
Thanks

Comment: Please show some code of your asmx

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attribute to your webMethod:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

It suppose to remove the methodName and the result tag.
For more information read this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1460873.aspx?Removing+result+tag+from+the+response+tag+in+a+soap+response

Comment: Any idea about changing SoapParameterStyle to Bare for every method? I mean, change default value for SoapParameterStyle w/o writing it at every single method.